# Docker backup and restore: 404 not found(nginx)

Tags: docker, nginx

I use docker this image.

> https://github.com/thomasvan/docker-wordpress-ubuntu16-nginx-php7

and I'm running this image, setting wordpress then try to backup container.

> docker commit -p CONTAINER_ID name

and make tar file.

> docker save -o name.tar name

and I was removed all container and images, and try to restore image.

> docker load -i name.tar

and,

> docker images

is successfully restore image...

But, I try to connect this server, and occurs '404 not found' message.

What did I do wrong?

I have tried many times, but have failed many times.

Is the backup / restore method wrong?

Comment: Did you run the container after loading? You need to run it yourself using `docker run`

Comment: @TarunLalwani Yes, I running docker conrtainer.

Comment: Post the logs showing 404